# Reason why experiments with small sample size should be excluded from a review

Tags: sample-size, sample, effect-size

I am currently conducting a literature review of Virtual Reality experiments with repeated measures of learning outcomes. Intuitively, experiments with small sizes (of experiment groups) have less power and thus I would like to exclude them. However, if the studies do not report any information on statistical power (and thus the required sample size), I wonder how I can argue that I exclude these studies? Do you know of any scientific literature that recommends considering experiments with a specific minimum sample size?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: There is no need to exclude studies because they have imprecise results as they will be appropriately weighted in meta-analysis.

Comment: @mdewey can you please elaborate what you mean with "appropriately weighted"? I actually do not want to compare the values as different outcome variables were measured so the term literature review is probably more appropriate than meta analysis

Comment: I mean using the usual inverse variance weighted meta-analysis. If you do not want to perform meta-analysis it might be better to remove that tag and edit your question to say that so people do not write answers which are irrelevant to your actual problem.

Comment: Exclude when the reject or fail to reject the null hypothesis?